# A Short Readable Note

Tags: cipher

Back in high school when I was in a math class, I came up with a brief note that I didn't end up sending. Can you tell what it says?

`!r!k6ⲗonrncⲗ`

There is no special context involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mirroring the message over the horizontal axis gives `iLiKeyouLucy` => `I like you Lucy`